# Increase in heap memory consumption and OOMs after upgrade to Java 17?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Recently, I upgraded a Docker image from `opendjk:11-jre` to `eclipse-temurin:17-jre`, and since the change has been performed I've just realised that the heap memory consumption has grown significantly (60MiB to 140MiB in some cases). I was wondering, is this a memory leak or misconfiguration in the flags when launching the image?

Also, I noticed that GC takes place way less times than before.

In Java 11, I had these options enabled so that memory consumption was uniform and no restarts due to OOMs were identified: `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled`, but now those options are long gone and cannot be used in Java 17.

Is there a clear reason for the increase in memory consumption and restarts due to OOMs? Am I missing some flags in Java 17?

Comment: Some garbage collectors require more memory than others for their own bookkeeping (that is, BTW, not Java heap memory). Likely you're now using G1GC, which requires more memory than the CMS-GC you were previously using. Also, each GC has its own memory-behaviour (e.g. some are likely to only allocate memory when really needed, while others are more prone to be generous in memory consumption to reduce CPU cost of GC, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for replying @MarkRotteveel, just did a quick test with the following command to see which GC would it choose with the pod specs `docker run --cpus=0.5 --memory=256Mi --rm -it eclipse-temurin:17-jre java -Xlog:gc\* -version` and the output is `[0.005s][info][gc] Using Serial`